# scikit-learn calculate F1 in multilabel classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I am trying to calculate macro-F1 with scikit in [multi-label classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification)

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_true = [[1,2,3]]
y_pred = [[1,2,3]]

print f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

However it fails with error message

```
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

How I can calculate macro-F1 with multi-label classification?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current scikit-learn release, your code results in the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Direct support for sequence of sequences multilabel
    representation will be unavailable from version 0.17. Use
    sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer to convert to a label
    indicator representation.
```

Following this advice, you can use [`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) to convert this multilabel class to a form accepted by `f1_score`. For example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_true = [[1,2,3]]
y_pred = [[1,2,3]]

m = MultiLabelBinarizer().fit(y_true)

f1_score(m.transform(y_true),
         m.transform(y_pred),
         average='macro')
# 1.0
```

Comment: Wondering how to achieve this for a multiple regression problem.